# Slow shutdown and cannot troubleshoot

Tags: shutdown

I have problems with a slow shutdown.  I followed the instructions to reduce the timeout.
EOS 5.1

I set the timeouts to 9 seconds as answered below but it does not work.

Comment: If you press the right arrow key while shutting down you'll see what's delaying the shutdown process. [Here](https://medium.com/@sbyang/slow-shut-down-of-ubuntu-18-04-e5fcc31255e2) you have a guide on how to reduce a delay on Ubuntu 18.04 and elementary Juno.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 sudo nano /etc/systemd/system.conf
```

and edit as the image then run

[image]

uncommented (remove the "#") the fields above to

```
DefaultTimeoutStopSec=9s
```

Then run this command to reload

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

if you find it still not working, set StartSec to 9s

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a bug related to cerbere. It’s discussed in more depth in [github](https://github.com/elementary/cerbere/issues/36)

The only workarounds that seems to work are:

- Set `DefaultTimeoutStopSec` to 10 or lower,    or
- Kill cerbere before shutdown