# Laptop won't turn off and requires holding power button

Tags: shutdown

I'm hoping you can help. I am a noob linux user. I installed elementary OS 5.1 on my laptop, originally I had an issue with updating apps and with turning the laptop off. App updates are now sorted, however when I turn off the laptop, it goes to a black screen with elementary logo. I have to hold the power button down at this point to turn it off. I am using a HP envy x360 laptop if that helps at all.

Comment: I would like to add, running the command 'shutdown now' in the terminal works without issue. Problem is only when I click the little red power button.

Comment: There's an issue with elementary having a slow shutdown in some circumstances. The sure giveaway is that it takes exactly 90 seconds. If that is it, here is the solution: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/18947/slow-shutdown-and-cannot-troubleshoot

Answer (score 1):

Now seems to be working fine, perhaps one of the updates fixed the problem, as I've seen that other people had a similar issue.