# long reboot Elementary OS

Tags: boot, shutdown

I've seen threads about long startup when booting Elementary OS or that its completely stuck when rebooting, but my problem is that it very often (not always) takes 90 sec. before the logo dissapears and the reboot starts. My question is what causes this erratic behaviour and how to solve it?

Made about 10 reboots (rebooting, shut downs) and it seems that in 75% of the cases it takes about 90 sec. before the reboot begins (before the logo dissapears). In 25% of the cases it reboots immediately.

I've tried to shut down every open applications (for instance webbrowsers with a lot of tabs) before rebooting/shut down without success

Using dual boot (Windows 10 and Elementary OS) and Grub.

cincerely

Answer (score 1):

[Slow shutdown and cannot troubleshoot](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/18947/slow-shutdown-and-cannot-troubleshoot)

Basically this is a common bug that can be resolved by reducing the default timeout.

Hint is that it is exactly 90 seconds.

Comment: thanks will look into this :-)